# Wants to receive total bytes from the client along with the data and how I have to handle it from other code

Tags: c#, websocket, networkstream

I am using a c# application that sends data to my server.
I want to send bytes along with the data so that I can handle at server code if the data size is large it can break there only.
I am not getting how to send bytes value along with the data.

The below is my client side sending part and my server side responding part to client.

Client Code :-

```
  public bool sendData(StringBuilder QueryVal)
    {
        TcpClient clientSocket = new System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient();
        try
        {

            clientSocket.Client.Connect(Serverip, 8888);
            var connect = clientSocket.Connected;// it can be ? clientSocket.Client.Connected
            if (connect == true)
            {
                try
                {
                    NetworkStream serverStream = clientSocket.GetStream();
                    byte[] outStream = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(QueryVal + "$");
                    serverStream.Write(outStream, 0, outStream.Length);
                    String decodedString = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(outStream);
                    decodedData(decodedString.ToString());

                    serverStream.Flush();
                    byte[] inStream = new byte[clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize];
                    serverStream.Read(inStream, 0, (int)clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize);
                    string returndata = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(inStream);

                    //MessageBox.Show("Receive data is: " + returndata);
                    int SendByte = outStream.Count();
                    int ReceivedByte = Convert.ToInt32(returndata);
                    try
                    {
                        clientSocket.Client.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
                    }
                    bool chk = clientSocket.Connected;// this line should be comment
                    if (SendByte == ReceivedByte) { return true; }
                    else { return false; }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    StackFrame objtrack = new StackFrame();
                    var methodinfo = objtrack.GetMethod();
                    string calssName = methodinfo.DeclaringType.Name;
                    string methoname = methodinfo.Name;
                    string Lineno = Convert.ToString(ex.LineNumber());
                    log(ex.Message, calssName, methoname, Lineno);
                    return false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            StackFrame objtrack = new StackFrame();
            var methodinfo = objtrack.GetMethod();
            string calssName = methodinfo.DeclaringType.Name;
            string methoname = methodinfo.Name;
            string Lineno = Convert.ToString(ex.LineNumber());
            log(ex.Message, calssName, methoname, Lineno);
            return false;
        }
    }
```

---

Server Code :-

```
 Byte[] sendBytesAA = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(ReceiveSize.ToString());
ReceiveSize = 0;
networkStream.Write(sendBytesAA, 0, sendBytesAA.Length);
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't convert data to string in can mess up the data and adds unnecessary processing time.  Try following code :

```
            TcpClient clientSocket = new TcpClient();

            NetworkStream serverStream = clientSocket.GetStream();

            List<byte> inStream = new List<byte>();
            serverStream.Read(inStream.ToArray(), 0, (int)clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize);
            long length = inStream.Count;
            byte[] byteLength = BitConverter.GetBytes(length);
            inStream.InsertRange(0, byteLength.ToList());
```